# Angular Child Routes Navigable without Parent Route

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have some routes in an Angular 13 app which load other modules that contain a number of child routes.

My routing is set up in each module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [DashboardComponent],
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(childRoutes)]})
export class ChildModule{}

export const childRoutes = [
    {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
    {path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent}];
```

My parent module lazy loads the child module:

```
export const appRoutes = [
    {path: 'store', component: StoreLayoutComponent,
     loadChildren: () => import('app/store/child.module').then(m => m.ChildModule)}];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    ...})
export class AppModule {}
```

Both the urls `https://localhost:4200/store/dashboard` and
`https://localhost:4200/dashboard` load the child `DashboardComponent`.

The second url shouldn't be valid. Why is it valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here was that the `StoreModule` was both being lazy loaded and appeared in the `app.module.ts` of the application. This created routes for the module both as a direct child of the `app.module` and also as a lazy loaded module at the correct address.

Removing the declaration of `StoreModule` from the imports statement of `app.module.ts` solved the problem.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the child routes within the `children`.

**Child**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [DashboardComponent],
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(childRoutes)]})
export class ChildModule{}

export const childRoutes = [{
children:[
    {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
    {path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent}]
}];
```

**Parent**

```
export const appRoutes = [
    {path: 'store', component: StoreLayoutComponent,
     loadChildren: () => import('app/store/child.module').then(m => m.ChildModule)}];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    ...})
```

Comment: Thanks, I refactored to this but I can still navigate to the child without the parent route in the URL. It hasn't fixed it.

I tried to create a Stackblitz showing the issue, but it works in the Stackblitz but not in my app. There must be something more complicated in my app that's causing it.

Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks so much, this wasn't what was wrong, but it helped me clean up my code and eventually led me to find the actual issue.

Comment: Just curious. What was wrong?

Comment: I had the child module both as a lazy loaded route, and included in the "import" section of the module. This was registering it as a child route of the root, and as the child of the parent route.